# Display different DateTime format and get different format

Tags: jquery, datetime

I've `jquery datepicker` that display selected date in `DD-M-YY` format but i want to get selected date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I tried something like this

```
$filter('date')($scope.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but its of no use. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try yy-MM-dd ?

Comment: yes but it didn't work

Comment: yy-mm-dd should work - see https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats